# Matching data from three tables in Sql Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have three tables `Despatch`, `Activation` and `Replaced` as below:

[image]

I want to compare data from all the three tables with **`Despatch`** table being base.

For example, if I enter LOTQty as 20 I should receive result based on following calculations:

1. It should match all the **`ProductNo`** under Lot 20 from **`Despatch`** table with **`ProductNo`** in **`Activation`** table. If match found(in this case Product3,4,5 & 6) then next it should check dates.
2. If **`Dispatch Date`** of matched ProductNo's are less than **`Activation Date`**  only then it should consider.(Product3's Dispatch Date is less than Activation Date. So we count it as 1 and similarly for all others). Hence we find 4 matches.
3. Product1 and Product2 did not found any match in Activation table. For such Product numbers we refer Replaced table. If match found (in this case Product1) it should compare **`Dispatch Date`** and **`Record Date`**. If **`Dispatch Date`** is lesser than **`Record Date`** only then we should consider the data(Product1's Dispatch date is less than RecordDate. So we count it as 1).
4. So now total quantity should be 5 i.e 4 by comparing **`Activation`** table and 1 by comparing with **`Replaced`** table.

The above are just sample table entries. My real tables contains many more columns which are trimmed to keep it simple. I tried preparing the query but I'm unable to find logic to cater my own requirement. Query I tried so far is as below:

```
select
(
    select distinct LOTQty
    from Despatch
    where LOTQty = '20'
)as LotQty

,(
    select COUNT(ProductNo)
    from Despatch
    where LOTQty = '20'
)as ApprovedQty

,(
    select distinct(DispatchDate)
    from Despatch
    where LOTQty = '20'
)as DispatchDate

,(
    select COUNT(ProductNo)
    from Activation
    where ProductNo in (select ProductNo from Despatch) and LotQty = '20'
)as Installed
```

This yields result as below:
[image]

Installed field says 4 as. But as per my above requirement result should be 5. How can I build my query to satisfy my requirement?
Help is deeply appreciated, Thanks in advance.

**EDIT1**
While comparing **`Despatch`** table's **`ProductNo`** with **`Activation`** and **`Replaced`**, there may be possibility that there might be entries for same **`ProductNo`** in both **`Activation`** and **`Replaced`** tables. Hence the query should first check with **`Activation`** table. If it finds a match for **`ProductNo`** there, it shuould not search for same **`ProductNo`** in **`Replaced`** table. Only those **`ProductNo`** which found no match in **`Activation`** table or whose **`DispatchDate`** is greater than **`Activation`** date should be matched with **`Replaced`** table.

**EDIT 2**
[image]

In the above diagram **`ApprovedQty`** should be 6 as there are only 6 ProductNo in **`Despatch`** table for lot 20.

For **`Installed`** it goes this way:

1. It first matches **`ProductNo`** from **`Despatch`** with **`ProductNo`** of **`Activation`** table for Lot 20. It find 5 matches (Product1,3,4,5,6). but as Product1's **`DispatchDate`** > **`ActivationDate`**, it takes the count as 4 ignoring Product1.
2. Next it tries to find match for leftover **`ProductNo`** from **`Despatch`** (Product1,2) with **`Replaced`** **`ProductNo`**. As **`Replaced`** table has no **`LotQty`** column it just match the **`ProductNo`**. It finds a match for Product1 (Though Product4 also matches here but as it's already considered from **`Activation`** it shouldn't be considered from **`Replaced`**). Now Product1's **`DispatchDate`** < **`RecordDate`** so it counts it as 1.
3. Now the total Installed is 4 from **`Activation`** and 1 from **`Replaced`** bringing total to 5 again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you could use left joins to do this. Try this query, with your sample data it produces the desired output, except for the `ApprovedQty`, but I don't get how you arrived at `12` for that with the sample data:

```
select 
    d.LOTQty, 
    ApprovedQty = count(d.ProductNo),
    d.DispatchDate,
    Installed = count(a.ProductNo) + count(r.ProductNo)
from 
    Despatch d 
left join 
    Activation a 
     on d.ProductNo = a.ProductNo 
    and d.DispatchDate < a.ActivationDate 
    and d.LOTQty = a.LOTQty
left join 
    Replaced r 
      on d.ProductNo = r.ProductNo 
     and d.DispatchDate < r.RecordDate
     -- only count Replaced when there is no match in Activation
     -- or DispatchDate is greater then ActivationDate
     and (a.ActivationDate is null or a.ActivationDate < d.DispatchDate)
where 
    d.LOTQty = 20
group by 
    d.LOTQty, d.DispatchDate
```

this would output:

```
LOTQty  ApprovedQty DispatchDate    Installed
20      6           2013-08-07      5
```

Comment: @ jpw I have edited my question again. In EDIT2, I have added one more image with bit of explanation which adds a bit more clarity. Hope this may help understand the scenario better... Thanks

Comment: @KC Not sure if I understand, but if you want the list of SerialNo and dates for the products in the installed category as a separate query I think maybe this might be it: http://pastebin.com/DbcQKxPH

Comment: @ jpw yes this was what I required, thanks. I'm trying on further things as per them. But if I end up making mistakes can I ask for help in comment(it is going quite long) or should I post a new question

Comment: @KC It would be better to ask a new question. I'll remove the comments I made here to clean up the post a bit.

Comment: @ jpw even ill clean up my comments reason being same as your's. I have posted a new question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29029135/extracting-data-from-ms-sql-server-2008-referring-multiple-tables). Million thanks to you.