# Extracting data from MS SQL Server-2008 referring multiple tables

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have had asked a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28853364/matching-data-from-three-tables-in-sql-server-2008/28855348?noredirect=1#comment46247073_28855348) and have got help from [jpw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1175077/jpw) who helped me with the query. The situation here remains same but only a bit more detail added. I have four tables. Sample structure for three of them is given below:
[image]

I have been helped to form query which goes as below:

```
select 
    d.LOTQty, 
    ApprovedQty = count(d.SerialNo),
    d.DispatchDate,
    Installed = count(a.SerialNo) + count(r.SerialNo)
from 
    Despatch d 
left join 
    Activation a 
     on d.SerialNo= a.SerialNo
    and d.DispatchDate <= a.ActivationDate 
    and d.LOTQty = a.LOTQty
left join 
    Replaced r 
      on d.SerialNo= r.SerialNo
     and d.DispatchDate <= r.ActivationDate
     and (a.ActivationDate is null or a.ActivationDate < d.DispatchDate)
where 
    d.LOTQty = 15
group by 
    d.LOTQty, d.DispatchDate, d.STBModel
```

For understanding sake, above query match **`Despatch`** table's `SerialNo` with **`Activation`** table. If match found it checks for Date difference. If `DespatchDate < ActivationDate` only those numbers are considered while others(which didn't match or whose `DispatchDate > ActivationDate`) are matched with Replaced with similar date criteria. So at the end we find 9 matches i.e 7 from **`Activation`** and 2 from **`Replaced`** as below:

```
LotQty | ApprovedQty | DispatchDate | Installed
  15   |      10     |   2013-8-7   |    9
```

I want to display two more columns in here i.e **`DOA`** and **`Bounce`** like this:

```
LotQty | ApprovedQty | DispatchDate | Installed | DOA | Bounce
  15   |      10     |   2013-8-7   |    9      |  2  |   4
```

DOA and Bounce should be calculated with difference between 4th table i.e **`Failed`** table's `FailedDate` and the above 9 matched SerialNo's respective Activation/Record date(henceforth termed as act_rec_date). **`Failed`** table and Intermediate 9 matched SerialNo's structure is shown below:

[image]

**`Intermediate`** table doesn't physically exist. It is just for reference and to provide more clarity. **`Intermediate`** table contain those `SerialNo`, which were matched with **`Activation`** and **`Replaced`** table. The `act_rec_Date` field is correspondingly matched Activation/Record Date.

1. **DOA & Bounce** = We should match all the 9 resultant SerialNo's(i.e Intermediate table) with **`Failed`** table. If matched, calculate difference between `FailedDate` and `act_rec_date`. If difference is **`(0 to <=10 days)`** then count it under `DOA` and if difference is **`(>10 days to <=180 days)`** then count it under `Bounce`. From **`Failed`** we find 6 matches out of which Product1,2 falls in `DOA` as difference between act_rec_Date is 0 and Product7,8,9 & 10 falls under `Bounce` as their difference is `89 | 54 | 61 | 61`. So as shown above **`DOA = 2`** and **`Bounce = 4`**

I want to build a query which could give me DOA and Bounce as well. I tried creating a temp table and dumping the resultant SerialNo's and act_rec_Date into it. Next I tried to match temp table and Failed table. I couldn't get it working and further more it took around 7 minutes to even execute the query.

P.S- My Actual tables contain around 50k to 100k data entries.

Answer (score 0):

Continuing on the previous query I think the new columns could be added with a conditional aggregation in the select statement and another left join for the failed table.

This should work, but I'm sure the query can be improved:

```
select 
    d.LOTQty, 
    ApprovedQty = count(d.SerialNo),
    d.DispatchDate,
    Installed = count(a.SerialNo) + count(r.NewSerialNo),
    DOA    = sum(case when datediff(day, coalesce(a.ActivationDate,r.RecordDate), f.FailedDate) <= 10 then 1 else 0 end),
    Bounce = sum(case when datediff(day, coalesce(a.ActivationDate,r.RecordDate), f.FailedDate) between 11 and 180 then 1 else 0 end)
from 
    Despatch d 
left join 
    Activation a 
     on d.SerialNo= a.SerialNo
    and d.DispatchDate <= a.ActivationDate 
    and d.LOTQty = a.LOTQty
left join 
    Replaced r 
      on d.SerialNo= r.NewSerialNo
     and d.DispatchDate <= r.RecordDate
     and (a.ActivationDate is null or a.ActivationDate < d.DispatchDate)
left join 
    Failed f 
      on (f.FailedSINo = a.SerialNo)
      or (f.FailedSINo = r.NewSerialNo)     
where 
    d.LOTQty = 15
group by 
    d.LOTQty, d.DispatchDate
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/611e8/2) with test data

Comment: @ jpw your query worked fine for sample data. But as I tried it with a bit larger sample say 60 -80 data in each table, the result was different. I tried pasting table scripts I used in SQL Fiddle but it blew off. So I have pasted my table's scripts from SQL-Server 2008 in [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/3wf4Y7Sm). Can you look over it? Expected answer for `LotQty`, `ApprovedQty`, `DispatchDate`, `Installed`, `DOA` and `Bounce` is **`47 | 47 | 2013-10-3 | 40 | 7 | 8`** but I got **`47 | 49 | 2013-10-3 | 40 | 7 | 7`** and for my real table the difference was even more

Comment: @KC I've looked at it and I can't get the same result, but instead I get 
`47 | 47 | 2013-10-31 | 40 | 7 | 7`. The reason it showed 49 for installed is because there are two products in the replaced table with two dates. I can't see how bounce can be 8 at all.

Comment: @ jpw but `ApprovedQty` should be shown solely based on **`Despatch`** table. **`Despatch`** table contains just 47 data entries and it should get only **count(SerailNo) from Despatch for lot 47**. In general it can be number equal to LotQty or less but never more. I'll check the data manually n let u know if `Bounce` I said was wrong. Thanks

Comment: @KC Yes, you can get the correct ApprovedQty by doing `ApprovedQty = count(distinct d.SerialNo),` but the bounce is still wrong.

Comment: @ jpw yea I checked it manually and `Bounce` is 7. The problem is this. When Im checking it on a chunk of sample data it's getting me correct result. But for same lot 47 if I check on my real table which has few thousands of data with few other Lot's, Im getting wrong result as **`47 | 47 | 2013-10-3 | 47 | 44 | 0`**

Comment: @KC Try commenting out everything in the select and the group by and do a select * instead to see what data is returned and maybe you'll spot the error.

Comment: @ jpw I tried spotting the error. For some reasons it's getting lot's of duplicates and few entries whose SerialNo's are not matching at all with **`Failed`** table. If I take sample data from my original table with single Lot entry, the query is giving desired result. But when Im trying it on my actual table with around 500 Lot Quantities it's getting all messed up... It would throw some light if I could provide actual table data, but there is no way I could do that. I don't know how to explain my issue here as it worked fine with the data I provided you...